# Ajax get request: reach an information in an html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to implement a jquery get request to a page that looks like that:

```
<tr class='tr'>
    <td class='example1'>
        <span> Information I have <span>
        <div> Something <div>
    </td>
    <td class='example2'>
        <span> Information I want to get <span>
        <span> something else </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the page, there are multiple 'TR', and what I want is to reach the one with 'Information I have' and get 'Information I want to get'.

I would like to use an ajax request:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "url_of_the_page",
        success: test
    });
}, 5000);

function test(html) {
    $(html).find("Information I have").each(function()
```

But I don't know how to reach the info.

Comment: Finding element with text content is an expensive operation . Why don't you specify any selectors to match that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$(html).find("span:contains('Information I have')").each( function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // do stuff with text
});
```

Just one thing worth mentioning. The above selector is case sensitive, so elements with `information` rather than `Information` will not be returned.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3aZ3j/)

Comment: In your example which bit of information do you want to take out? _Something else_??

Comment: @Juliette If I answered your question you could mark it as such :)